# using Another In Place Editor Jquery Plugin on mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i am trying to `insert` data as a test for this JQuery plugin [Jquery-in-place-editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/), which doesn't work so far with me, here is what i did :

1. i connected my server with mysql database, and to test the db
   functionality, i made a table called `test` with tow fields `id`
   which is PK and auto increment, and `userUserName` with datatype
   `varchar`.
2. i pluged the jquery plugin as the instructions says and the script works perfectly for the css and editing

the problem is when i change any text , not thing happend on the server.

here is my code:

JQuery Plugin

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#editme1").editInPlace({
            url: "server.php",
            params: "name=david",
        });
    });
```

the `name=david` came with the script and it used on his demo test file, and because i am still rookie i do not know wether it affect my script or not.

Server.php (server-side file)

```
function Sqlconnection(){
$connection= mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","123") or die (mysql_error());
$db= mysql_select_db("reservebox",$connection) or die (mysql_error());
            }


Sqlconnection();

 $update = $_POST['update_value'];

$insert ="insert into test (userUserName) values ($update)";

mysql_query($insert) or die (mysql_error());
```

the `$_POST['update_value']` should be the value that comes when i change the div `editme1`

div `editme1`

```
   <p id="editme1">
                    This example is with 
no options except for a callback 
that will handle the value when the edit is complete.
                </p>
```

can some explaing to me where do i go wrong here , i made sure the the jquery is attached and so the other required files , i used the `demo` file with script and it doesn't work also !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the library js file ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.editinplace.js"></script>
```

And you have an extra comma in your question, this can also break the plugin to load.
Look at the comment line :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#editme1").editInPlace({
        url: "server.php",     //  you mentioned the file name as 'Server.php'
        params: "name=david", // this comma should not come here
    });
});
```